# Setting up Java compiler on Windows laptop

Tags: java, compiler-construction, path, windows-7-x64

I have a laptop with a Windows 7 OS 64-bit. I'm trying to set up the Java compiler so when I type in "javac" in the command prompt, it will compile the Java file I want. I've had it done on my laptop before but someone did it for me. They went to the Environment Variables under the Advanced System settings, then edited the "PATH" so that it would recognized the compiler. So I did the exact same thing, I copied the file location of javac from ProgramFiles, and put it in PATH. It still does not compile my Java files. It says:

> "javac" is not recognized as an internal or external command.

And before you ask, I did search through other forums on this site to see if there was an answer that can help. There are similar situations to mine but the solutions did not help me.

As of now, this is the file path that I tried copying into `PATH`: 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin` This leads to a file marked javac. So far I'm still unsuccessful with setting up the compiler.

Comment: you might need to re-login or reboot the computer depending on how Windows takes the new path.

Comment: Existing command prompt windows will not pick up environment variable changes.  You can verify your path in Windows with `echo %PATH%`.  You may need to start a new command prompt window.

Comment: You need to exit the command prompt and open a new one after changing the environment. @user2264997 Definitely not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct. Did you restart the Command prompt every time you changed the PATH variable ? Also there's supposed to be only one path variable, so you're supposed to edit the existing one, entries are separated by a semi-colon (;).

Comment: You were right. Everything was correct but for some reason it didn't work. Why? I don't know. I had to uninstall everything from Oracle off my computer then reinstall it and the PATH finally worked. Thank you for the help.